# What is wrong with my Flutter app that sends HTTP requests with a button?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I want to build a simple app that just sends an http request to a server, gets a response and displays it's body inside a Text Widget, but it seems like I can't figure out how to design everything to be elegant, efficient and easy to understand.
I also want to make sure only the Text Widget gets rebuilt and not anything else.
In the actual state, it also throws an "Unexpected null value" on the FutureBuilder.

```
class ApiDataProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  final String _urlPath;
  Future<http.Response>? _response;

  ApiDataProvider(this._urlPath);

  Future<http.Response> get response {
    var responseCopy = _response;
    if (responseCopy != null) {
      return responseCopy;
    } else {
      responseCopy = fetch();
      return responseCopy;
    }
  }

  Future<http.Response> fetch() async {
    var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(Server.address + _urlPath));
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      notifyListeners();
      return response;
    } else {
      throw Exception("Could not fetch resources.");
    }
  }
}

class HttpTestScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HttpTestScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<HttpTestScreen> createState() => _HttpTestScreenState();
}

class _HttpTestScreenState extends State<HttpTestScreen> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    context.read<ApiDataProvider>().fetch();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                context.read<ApiDataProvider>().fetch();
              },
              child: const AutoSizeText(
                'Send HTTP Request',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 25,
                ),
              ),
            ),

            const SizedBox(height: 25),

            Consumer<ApiDataProvider>(
              builder: (_, requestModel, __) => FutureBuilder(
                  future: requestModel.response,
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                      return AutoSizeText(
                        snapshot.data!.body,
                        minFontSize: 15,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 28,
                        ),
                      );
                    }
                    return const CircularProgressIndicator();
                  }),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```